# SQL insert statement for each update row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Now i made cursor to update in 2 tables and insert in one table based on specific select statement this select statement return 2 columns x , y i need x to update in table "PX" because x is Primary key in this table and need x to update in table "FX" because x is foreign key in this table then insert in third table x data.

I need to change this cursor and use update and insert script i tried but i found that i need to make loop to achieve my target so if any one know if i can change this cursor .

And thanks in advance

```
DECLARE @id int
DECLARE @clientid uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @code int
DECLARE @Wtime int

DECLARE @closeComplaint CURSOR
SET @closeComplaint = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD 
FOR
    SELECT ComplaintId, [ClientId]
    FROM complaint
    WHERE ComplaintStatusId = 5  
      AND (waitingForCutomerCloseDateTime < GETDATE() OR
           waitingForCutomerCloseDateTime = GETDATE())   

OPEN @closeComplaint

FETCH NEXT FROM @closeComplaint INTO @id, @clientid

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        waitingForCutomerCloseTime = @Wtime 
    FROM
        SystemConfiguration 
    WHERE
        ClientId = @clientid

    SELECT 
        [Code] = @code 
    FROM
        [dbo].[resp_users] 
    WHERE
        ClientId = @clientid

    UPDATE activity 
    SET ActivityStatus = 4, 
        CompletionDate = GETDATE(),
        ClosedBy = @code 
    WHERE [ComplaintId] = @id

    UPDATE [dbo].[Complaint] 
    SET ComplaintStatusId = 2 
    WHERE [ComplaintId] = @id

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Note] ([Note_Description], [ClientId], [User_Code], [Visible_Internal],
                              [ComplaintId], [Note_DateTime], [ComplainantId],
                              [OneStopDesk_CustomerEmail], [OneStopDesk_CustomerUsername], [Private])
    VALUES (N'Automatically closed by system after ' + @Wtime, @clientid, @code, 1,
            @id, GETDATE(), null, null, null, 1)

    FETCH NEXT FROM @closeComplaint INTO @id, @clientid
END

CLOSE @closeComplaint
DEALLOCATE @closeComplaint
```

Comment: Without seeing your code, we really cannot make any suggestions on how to modify it.  Edit your question and include the code.

Comment: why you include C# tag? this looks like a pure sql.

Comment: i added my sql code @marc_s

Comment: i added my sql code@Gordon Linoff

Comment: please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) your description is very vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not **entirely** sure I got everything right (you didn't post the table structures, so I can really only *guess* at times how those tables are connected) - but you should be able to basically do all of this in **3 simple, set-based** statements - and that should be a **LOT** faster than the cursor!

```
-- declare table variable
DECLARE @Input TABLE (CompaintID INT, ClientID INT)

-- save the rows into a table variable
INSERT INTO @Input (ComplaintID, ClientID)
   SELECT ComplaintID, ClientID
   FROM dbo.Complaint
   WHERE ComplaintStatusId = 5
     AND waitingForCustomerCloseDateTime <= GETDATE()

UPDATE a 
SET ActivityStatus = 4, 
    CompletionDate = GETDATE(),
    ClosedBy = u.Code
FROM dbo.Activity a
INNER JOIN @Input i ON a.ComplaintId = i.ComplaintId
INNER JOIN dbo.resp_users u ON i.ClientId = u.ClientId

UPDATE dbo.Complaint
SET ComplaintStatusId = 2 
WHERE 
    ComplaintStatusId = 5
    AND waitingForCustomerCloseDateTime <= GETDATE()

INSERT INTO dbo.Note ([Note_Description], [ClientId], [User_Code], [Visible_Internal],
                      [ComplaintId], [Note_DateTime], [ComplainantId],
                      [OneStopDesk_CustomerEmail], [OneStopDesk_CustomerUsername], [Private])
    SELECT
        N'Automatically closed by system after ' + sc.waitingForCustomerCloseTime, 
        i.ClientId, u.Code, 1,
        i.ComplaintId, GETDATE(), null, null, null, 1
    FROM
        @Input i
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.SystemConfiguration sc ON i.ClientId = sc.ClientId
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.resp_user u ON u.ClientId = i.ClientId
```